# Fastest way to navigate to directories across varying revision trees within emacs

Tags: emacs, navigation, directory, bookmarks

I use Emacs and a revision tracker (perforce) for work-related things.

I have numerous (~10) different clients for Perforce that all have the same file structure. I would like to make generic commands to navigate to directories within these clients in Emacs.

However, the client paths are different. I want to make the navigation across directories be independent of the client name; instead, the client name should dynamically be determined.

For example, here are various paths to my clients:

```
/home/scratch/client1/hw/unit1/
/home/scratch2/client2/hw/unit2/
/home/scratch3/client3/hw/unit1/
```

As you can see, the path to each client varies, although the same structure is followed. Within each of these clients, the file structure is identical. So, each client's unit file will have the same structure (ie. `ip/src/` or some equivalent path)

I see a lot of solutions for bookmarking directories to quickly jump to them, but I need something that works dynamically across all of my clients that have slightly different paths. Currently, if I use the bookmarks functionality, it will copy my whole client path to the directory, not a path based on the client I am currently in.

To me, that would mean I need something that dynamically determines the location of the client, and then shows the same bookmarked files within each client.

So, say I want the following three bookmarked directories to show based on the current client I am in:

```
/path/to/client/ip/src/bin
/path/to/client/ip/src/etc
/path/to/client/ip/src/inc
```

How can I do this in Emacs so that the client path (`/path/to/client/`) is dynamically figured out based on where I launched Emacs and then it appends the actual path within the client to the client path (`ip/src/bin`).

NOTE: I do have bash aliases to quickly navigate to directories independent of the client name. But I would like to minimize switching between Emacs and the command line as much as possible by finding a solution that works right inside of Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the path to the current client available in an environment variable? If so then you can use that variable in what you type to `find-file`.  It will be expanded during completion.
2. The directory where Emacs itself was invoked is the value of variable `invocation-directory`.  If your client location is easily determined from that (*"client path (`/path/to/client/`) is dynamically figured out based on where I launched Emacs"*), then you can define a command that reads a file (or directory) name in your client directory.

For #2, how is your *"client path (`/path/to/client/`) ... dynamically figured out based on where [you] launched Emacs"*?  If you show that code then the rest should be trivial.